# How do I handle multiple Submit buttons in plugin's option page?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, options

I'm developing my first plugin for WordPress and I'm getting a grasp of the whole hook system. I'm now stuck on a (probably) small issue, that I could possibly circumvent, but I'm afraid of coming out with a "hack", more than a real solution.

What I'm trying to do is putting two submit buttons on my Options page:

- Save
- Draft

Both of them would have to do something common (i.e. Saving the content of the form), but then they should take different action with such content. So far, I managed to ouput the two buttons using the following code:

```
echo '<form id="my_plugin_settings_form" method="post" action="options.php">';
settings_fields('my_plugin_settings');
do_settings_sections('my_plugin_settings');
submit_button(__('Save', 'MyPlugin'), 'Save');
submit_button(__('Draft', 'MyPlugin'), 'secondary','Draft');
echo '</form>';
```

I also implemented a validate method, which correctly receives the posted fields:

```
public function validate_settings($settings) {
  var_dump($settings); // Here I can see all posted fields
}
```

The above works well, with all the data being saved correctly in WordPress Options table. However, I would like to "intercept" the data being saved to manipulate it. I was thinking of manipulating the data within the `validate_settings()` method, but the button that was clicked is **not** included in the settings passed as an argument.

I could simply parse the `$_POST` array to get it, but I'm having the doubt that the approach is a bit of a hack and, that, perhaps, I should implement a proper hook, somewhere else.

My question, therefore, is: where should I put my code to process the data posted from an Options page? Is there a specific hook I should use?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Getting what you need out of `$_POST` is fine (as long as you validate and sanitize properly), that's how forms work after all. There probably is a way to wrangle button data into Settings API flow, but it is a mess and there will be little _practical_ difference to what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings API is crap. I need a long time and need try many until I got this working. My problem was that the values from my inputs never was passed to the validate callback.

I end up in using the array method:

```
<input type="text" name="foo[bar]" value="baz" />
```

If the formular will be send, in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array is a field called `foo` that contains an array with all values. So I can access the value with e.g. `$_POST['foo']['bar']`

If I had to work with the settings API, I use the second parameter fomr `register_setting()` (the option name) as key for my input fields.

```
global $option_name;
$option_group = 'The_Option_Group';
$option_name = 'The_Option_Name';
register_setting( $option_group, $option_name );
[...]

function field_callback() {
  global $option_name;
  echo "<input type='text' name='{$option_name}[bar]' value='baz' />";
  echo "<input type='submit' name='{$option_name}[submit]' value='Send' />"
}
```

In this way I can access all values within the formular in the option validate callback.

```
function option_validate( $input ) {
  $bar = $input['bar'];
  $sub = $input['submit'];

  return $input;
}
```

It's better explained in the article [Settings API Explained](http://www.presscoders.com/2010/05/wordpress-settings-api-explained/) on PressCoders